# How can I wipe a flash drive from Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, wipe

I recently used a flash drive to try MeeGo on my netbook. Unfortunately, the application I used to write MeeGo to the flash drive created a new partition in a rather unusual format. The Ubuntu disk utility can't delete the partition, and GParted can't even see it. How can I completely wipe the flash drive from Ubuntu? I'd prefer not to install any additional software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `fdisk`? In a terminal, run

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdx
```

where `/dev/sdx` should be replaced with the device file for your flash drive. Once you get `fdisk` open, type `p` to list the partition table, and if the mysterious partition is listed, you can use `d #` to delete it. (`#` is the number of the partition, so e.g. `d 1`, `d 2`) `w` writes the partition table back to the disk and `q` quits. (hit `m` for help)

If even `fdisk` fails, I guess you could just try zeroing out the first sector, which I think contains the partition table.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1
```

where, again, `/dev/sdx` should be replaced with the actual device for your flash drive, will do that for you. You can increase the `count=` number to write zeros to more of the disk, or omit it entirely to overwrite the entire disk. Needless to say, if you do this, you irretrievably lose any files that may have been stored on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to have a bit more security, you can use random digits instead of zeros:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=128
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [flash_erase](https://github.com/vamanea/mtd-utils) which is part of [MTD (Memory Technology Devices)](http://linux-mtd.infradead.org/source.html) drivers.

```
sudo flash_erase --help
```

gives:

```
Usage: flash_erase [options] MTD_DEVICE <start offset> <block count>
Erase blocks of the specified MTD device.
Specify a count of 0 to erase to end of device.

  -j, --jffs2       format the device for jffs2
  -N, --noskipbad   don't skip bad blocks
  -u, --unlock      unlock sectors before erasing
  -q, --quiet       do not display progress messages
      --silent      same as --quiet
      --help        display this help and exit
      --version     output version information and exit
```

Comment: This will not work with USB and other drives https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/wiki/engineering/HOWTO_Use_MTD